# Getting error during Device Owner provisioning

Tags: android, device, owner

I am working on a MDM application which is a Device admin app, Now I am trying to move it to Device Owner. I used Android Management API and generated Enrolment Token. I have uploaded my APK in  S3 bucket and given that downloadable link In QR code Json.  After factory reset, I am clicking 6 times on the screen and scanning the QR code, after connecting to WIFI, it says "Device belongs to your organization" . When I click on Next button, I an getting a popup saying that "CAN"T SETUP DEVICE, CONTACT YOUR IT ADMIN FOR HELP". How to fix this. what all things I need to handle in my android code. How will my app get downloading when scanned the QR code. Here is my Json for QR code.

Note : We don't have any EMM Console of our own

```
{
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "com.android.client/com.android.utils.AdminReceiver",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM": "checksum generated from dowloaded APK",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION": "https://android-android.s3.eu-1.amazonaws.com/Android-74.apk",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE": {
"com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc.EXTRA_ENROLLMENT_TOKEN": "YLEHSBDKDBDWTJESJGOLAFKN"
}
}

{
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "com.android.client/com.android.utils.AdminReceiver",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM": "checksum generated from dowloaded APK",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION": "https://android-android.s3.eu-1.amazonaws.com/Android-74.apk",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE": {
"com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc.EXTRA_ENROLLMENT_TOKEN": "YLEHSBDKDBDWTJESJGOLAFKN"
}
}
```